# Choosing a ML algorithm: is MLP + SHAP suitable for binary classification with small amount of data points but large amount of features?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

My data frame is around 32 data points (patients) x 1000 features (numerical blood biomarkers, eg. glucose concentration, protein concentration, etc.). I am classifying medical information with 1 or 0: diagnosis or no diagnosis (already given - so it's a supervised learning task). I want to show which of the feature or combinations of features best predicts the diagnosis.

I think using a Multilayer Perceptron (MLP) network to do the classification, with SHAP (Shapley Additive Predictions) to show the best predictive feature(s) may be the best bet.  Would anyone more knowledgeable recommend a different technique to start with? Is this even possible with sample size of 32?

Answer (score 0):

32 data points are far too little to use any neural network, and it's very hard to extract any reliable information from such a tiny dataset with *any* method. Anything that comes out of your analysis is very likely simply noise. Sorry.

That said, your best bet will likely be a classical logistic regression with regularization. Take a look at [GLMNet](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnet.html) implementations, available [in the `glmnet` package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html).